# Calling amazon API several times in paralell runs into throtteling limit

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, callback

i am facing some Problems with my Amazon Project

This is my current situation:

I am trying to import many articles from amazon with their api using many search items.

This is how i am actually calling my function:

```
opHelper.execute('ItemSearch', {
    'SearchIndex': SearchIndex,
    'Keywords': array[2],
    'ResponseGroup': 'ItemAttributes',
    'Condition': 'All'
}).then((response) => {
    for (var a = 0; a <= response.result.ItemSearchResponse.Items[0].Item.length; a++) {
        opHelper.execute('ItemLookup', {
            'ItemId': response.result.ItemSearchResponse.Items[0].Item[a].ASIN[0],
            'MechantId': 'All',
            'Condition': 'All',
            'ResponseGroup': 'Medium'
        }).then((response) => {
            //Here im doing that persisting stuff...
        }).catch((err) => { // catch for each error
           console.log(err+" foreach");
        });
    }
}).catch((err) => { // catch first lookup error
        console.log(err+" first search response");
    });
```

As you can see, i am looking up for just one search item and therefore i am getting an ASIN array - for each of them i am doing a itemlookup.

All of this works fine until i run this more than one time - amazon only allows on request per second per IP... as you can imagine if these functions runs several times in parallel i will hit this limit not just once. :(

I tried some stuff like while(ready == false) on the end of the iteration to await the status of the first function...

Is there a way in node where i wont block the single thread and run a function after another?

Thank you,

Greetings
Niklas